# No se porque no se aplica mi CSS y Bootstrap al mismo tiempo

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

No entiendo porque no se aplica mi etiqueta CSS a los links, si alguien me pudier decir el error,
Yo supongo que no se esta aplicando Mi CSS por culpa de mi bootstrap, pero no se como solucionarlo sin sacar ninguno de mi codigo.

Soy nuevo tanto en CSS como Bootstrap y HTML

```css
 a {
        text-decoration: none; 
    }
```

```html
<!-- HTML Y BOOSTRAP -->

    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="es">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>API rest</title>
        <!-- Boostrap-->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="Bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <!-- CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" src="style.css">

    </head>
    <body>

        <!-- barra de navegación(con pestañas) -->
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" aria-current="page" href="#Más vendidos">Active</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">link</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">link</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">link</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">link</a>
            </li>
        </ul>

        <!-- más vendidos-->
        <div class="container">

        </div>
        <br>
        <h2 id="Más vendidos">Más vendidos</h2>
        <br>

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col">
                    <a href="#producto">
                        <div class="card" style="width: 13rem;">
                            <img src="..." class="img-card-top" alt="...">
                            <div class="card-body">
                                <h5 class="card-title">Adidas</h5>
                                <p class="card-text"> 
                                    botas niño
                                    <br>
                                    talle: 42 
                                    <h5> 42.357 </h5>
                                </p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="col">
                    <a class="text-decoration:none" href="#producto">
                        <div class="card" style="width: 13rem;">
                            <img src="..." class="img-card-top" alt="...">
                            <div class="card-body">
                                <h5 class="card-title">Adidas</h5>
                                <p class="card-text">
                                    botas niño
                                    <br>
                                    talle: 42 
                                    <h5> 42.357 </h5>
                                </p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="col">
                    <a class="text-decoration:none" href="#producto">
                        <div class="card" style="width: 13rem;">
                            <img src="..." class="img-card-top" alt="...">
                            <div class="card-body">
                                <h5 class="card-title">Adidas</h5>
                                <p class="card-text"> 
                                    botas niño
                                    <br>
                                    talle: 42 
                                    <h5> 42.357 </h5>
                                </p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="col">
                    <a class="text-decoration:none" href="#producto">
                        <div class="card" style="width: 13rem;">
                            <img src="..." class="img-card-top" alt="...">
                            <div class="card-body">
                                <h5 class="card-title">Adidas</h5>
                                <p class="card-text"> 
                                    botas niño
                                    <br>
                                    talle: 42 
                                    <h5> 42.357 </h5>
                                </p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="col">
                    <a class="text-decoration:none" href="#producto">
                        <div class="card" style="width: 13rem;">
                            <img src="..." class="img-card-top" alt="...">
                            <div class="card-body">
                                <h5 class="card-title">Adidas</h5>
                                <p class="card-text"> 
                                    botas niño
                                    <br>
                                    talle: 42 
                                    <h5> 42.357 </h5>
                                </p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>

        
        <!-- Muestras de zapatos de ofertas -->

    <script src="Boostrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Quiero borrar las lineas azules de los links de mis tarjetas a travez de CSS pero dejar mi Bootstrap para conservar las tarjetas.
Vi otra pregunta de estack overflow similar, pero no entiendo como resolvieron el problema, dicen que hay que ser muy especificos con lo que usa tu CSS y BOOSTRAP

Comment: Saludos. Sugerencia (casí no me meto con CSS); prueba el **text-decoration: none;**  poniendolo **text-decoration: none !important;**; ojo que el comportamiento lo forza a todo lo que sea **a** en la pagina donde cargues esa hoja de estilo. Te sugiero hacerlo como una clase si quiere sea a algunos **a** que aplique y se lo asignas explicitamente.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podrías agregar el estilo directo en el head si solo vas a modificar eso

```
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>API rest</title>
<!-- Boostrap-->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="Bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<!-- CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" src="style.css">
<style>
a {
    text-decoration: none !important; 
}
</style>

</head>
```

De igual manera podrías agregarle la propiedad !important en tu hoja de css y cambiar el "src" por "href", con eso te debe respetar lo de estilo

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
<!-- Boostrap-->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="Bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

Answer (score 0):

si la ruta de tu archivo esta bien así como la pusiste lo que indica que tu archivo CSS esta en la misma raíz de tu archivo HTML:

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" src="style.css">
```

Entonces puedes hace lo siguiente:

en las etiquetas `<a>` que desees cambiar quitar el subrayado azul puedes darles una clase asi:

```
 <a class="enlaces" href="#producto">
```

bueno la clase puede ser el nombre que tu quieras.

Luego en las reglas CSS haces referencia a esa clase:

```
.enlaces {
   text-decoration: none;
}
```

y listo